# Настройка логирования GC

Tags: java

Сделал тестовый класс и запускаю его такой командой (`java 8`):

```
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:NewRatio=3 -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps App
```

В ответ получаю ошибку:

```
Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCTimeStamps'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Аналогичная ситуация происходит с `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` и `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`.

В чем дело и как правильно настроить ?

Comment: а ява точно не 9?